# How to get a word between two expressions in AWK?

Tags: regex, text, awk

I want to get the name out of an html like this using AWK:

```
span class="full-name" span class="given-name" John /span span class="family-name" Doe /span  /span
```

So I want to extract `John` and `Doe` from it, by cutting the part after `... "given-name"` until `/span` and also the family name.

Could you help me with that?

Comment: You might want to insert the `<` and `>` again.

Comment: Does it *have* to be in `awk`?

Comment: of course with < and >... sorry, it was too late...not necessarily, any solition is welcome. thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what happened to your question regarding the `<` and `>` symbols. As I understand it, your html looks like this:

```
<span class="full-name"><span class="given-name">John</span><span class="family-name">Doe</span></span>
```

You could use `GNU grep` like this to get the tags you want:

```
grep -oP '(?<=-name">)[^<]*' file
```

Results:

```
John
Doe
```

Comment: this worked for me:

BEGIN{ FS="[<>\"]" }
{ if( $1=="" && $2 == "span class=" && $3=="full-name" && $7=="given-name" && $13=="family-name"  )
  print  $9 ";" $15}